# Is "start" used with "fire" as a transitive or an intransitive verb?

Tags: grammar, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

Should I say ***The fire is reported to have started by accident.*** or ***The fire is reported to have been started by accident.***

P.S:Someone told me to use the former because "by accident" implies that no one really started the fire,but I am not sure if she is trustworthy.

Comment: "I accidentally set fire to the leaves while raking them."

Comment: Road Traffic Accidents (RTAs) are no longer referred to, as such. They are now Road Traffic Collisions (RTCs). The thinking is that nothing is, really, an 'accident'. Someone did something. And someone is culpable.

Comment: In the second sentence, *by accident* is acting as the 'by + agent' in a passive voice sentence, or at least it can create such an ambiguity! *Start* is an intransitive verb too, and 'to have started' seems more natural.

Answer (score 0):

If a fire *was started*, someone did something, deliberately or accidentally, to set it going.

If a fire *started*, something became hot enough to begin to burn. Maybe it was someone's fault that the conditions were right for this to happen, but the fire wasn't the immediate result of anyone's action.

Comment: Thanks,but the problem is that it was in an exam and I had to choose between both sentences so I am asking which sentence is correct rather the meaning of each one.I hope you help me with this.

Comment: I can't see that either sentence is grammatically incorrect. Either could make sense, as I explained.

Comment: No. "The fire started **following a matchstick being thrown at it.**" could have been the full sentence, who knows?

Answer (score -2):

Not commenting on anyone's trustworthiness but the verb *start* can be either transitive or intransitive in this case.

Note that the two versions do not mean the same, and *by accident* is irrelevant here.

Comment: OP is asking about the meaning of the sentences. By accident is the core of the issue here.

Comment: My answer tries to explain why it is not.

Comment: @Kris  Could you explain the difference between both sentences?

Comment: Wouldn't you say that "The fire is reported to have been started" (omitting the 'by accident') implies that it was started deliberately by a human?

Comment: @FlorisSA No way. There's nothing to suggest "deliberate" or "accidental" -- it's silent on that aspect.